# "soup" or "a soup"

Tags: articles

I am learning Duolingo English course, one sentence is **we make soup with pieces of meat.** and the other one is **We make a soup with the roots.** When should I use **a**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be tricky when *make* is in the present tense. Let's say I regularly make three kinds of soup: taratino soup, squamil soup, and Droverly soup.

Let's also say that I put chicken in all three recipes. In that case, it would be fitting to say:

> I make soup with chicken.

Now, let's add one more fact: I use fresh kale when I make my squamil soup, but neither taratino soup nor Droverly soup use kale. In that case, I can say:

> I make **a** soup with fresh kale.

I think it's worth pointing out that, in this context, we are dealing with Definition #6 from [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/a):

[image: meanings of "a"]

---

Now, let's move to the past tense. Suppose I made soup last night, and I used some orzo. I can say either:

> I made soup with orzo last night.
>   I made a soup with orzo last night.

There's no difference in meaning; they both mean the same thing.

Likewise, there's no difference when we use the present progressive tense:

> I am making a soup with leeks.
>   I am making soup with leeks.

That's because *soup* can act as a mass noun (so no article would be required), but it can also take an article, whereby *a soup* essentially means *a **batch of** soup*.

Comment: Isn't there something else going on in case of _the_ roots? It may be me, but "I use the whole plant: I make stew with the leafs, I deep fry the stalks and I make soup with the roots" does not sound as good as a version with "a stew" and "a soup".

Comment: @oerkelens - I agree, but there are other scenarios where omission of the article would be okay. For example: _"When my brother cooks, he only uses the greens, but I like to make soup with the roots."_

Comment: I am starting to realize it was a good idea I did not try to answer this, and also, this question could be interesting on ELU :)